# How can i search documents based on multiple geopoints in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a usecase where I want to search for documents with multiple geopoints.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "100m",
          "nc_extraData.nc_geoPoint": {
            "lat": 21.36042723377568,
            "lon": -5.646749208228298
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query suppports only for single geopoint. Is it possible.

Comment: You can add several `geo_distance` constraints with different geo points.

Comment: Can you please let me know the query for the same. As I am finding it hard to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can add several `geo_distance` constraints with different geo points. You can also know which point matched using [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-queries-and-filters):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "100m",
            "nc_extraData.nc_geoPoint": {
              "lat": 21.36042723377568,
              "lon": -5.646749208228298
            },
            "_name": "point 1"
          }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "100m",
            "nc_extraData.nc_geoPoint": {
              "lat": 22.36042723377568,
              "lon": -6.646749208228298
            },
            "_name": "point 2"
          }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "100m",
            "nc_extraData.nc_geoPoint": {
              "lat": 23.36042723377568,
              "lon": -7.646749208228298
            },
            "_name": "point 3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I didn't make my point clear. The thing is that I have multiple geopoints for each point i need to find the documents which are 100m distance. I don't want to for loop for each point. Do ES gives something that I can get in a single query. Because as in above query I cant correlate for which geopoint the documents are closer. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Please check my post. I am bit confused why matched queries contain both the names.

Comment: If a document contains two query names it means that the document matched two of the queries.

Answer (score 0):

````
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "6000km",
            "nc_extraData.nc_geoPoint": {
              "lat": 39.783181787374076,
              "lon": -100.72051270885312
            },
            "_name": "point 1"
          }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "6000km",
            "nc_extraData.nc_geoPoint": {
              "lat": 39.73750007106965,
              "lon": -90.00078544604122
            },
            "_name": "point 2"
          }
        },
         {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "1000m",
            "nc_extraData.nc_geoPoint": {
              "lat": 60.73750007106965,
              "lon": -90.00078544604122
            },
            "_name": "point 3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}```

I am trying this query. But the matching query contains both ``` "matched_queries": [
                    "point 2",
                    "point 1"
                ]``
````